# Discord.js Run the code at the fount after running a later code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to ask is it possible to run the code at the beginning after running the code inside the beginning one? Like here is my code and I'll talk more about what I exactly want to do.

```js
SendEmbed.awaitReactions(
  (reaction, user) =>
    user.id == message.author.id && ["1️⃣", "2️⃣"].includes(reaction.emoji.name),
  { max: 1, time: 10000 }
)
  .then((collected) => {
    if (collected.first().emoji.name == "1️⃣") {
      const NewEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#55FF55")
        .setTitle("OOF")
        .setDescription(`${message.author.tag} has add reaction 1️⃣`);
      SendEmbed.edit(NewEmbed);
      SendEmbed.reactions.removeAll();
      SendEmbed.react("1️⃣");
      SendEmbed.react("2️⃣");
      return;
    } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == "2️⃣") {
      const NewEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#55FF55")
        .setTitle("OOF")
        .setDescription(`${message.author.tag} has add reaction 2️⃣`);
      SendEmbed.edit(NewEmbed);
      SendEmbed.reactions.removeAll();
      SendEmbed.react("1️⃣");
      SendEmbed.react("2️⃣");
      return;
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    message.channel.send("Time out");
  });
```

so here is my code and I want to ask is it possible to run the code again starts from

```
SendEmbed.awaitReactions ...
```

after it finished running the code at

```
if (collected.first().emoji.name == '1️⃣') {
```

or

```
} else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '2️⃣') {
```

either (which means it goes back to SendEmbed.awaitReactions when the person has already reacted to the message and then it goes up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enclose your repeating unit within a single function** and call **recursively** at the end of execution.

Here's an example:

```js
function recursive() {
 console.log('Waiting for input');
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('Input received and processed');
   resolve(5);
   recursive();
  }, 3000);
 });
}
recursive();
```

About your example:

```js
function listen() {
 SendEmbed.awaitReactions()
  .then((collected) => {
   executeLogic();
   listen();
  })
  .catch(() => {
   handleError();
   listen();
  });
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! I finally understand how can this work!

Comment: but it said handleError is not defined. Did I miss something?

Comment: no executeLogic() & handleError() aren't functions. it is to tell you to **execute logic** & **handle error** ;)